# Match dollar sign and first letter after

Tags: php, regex

I have some weird database entries, that looks like this:

```
$sSomeTextHere$uTextAgain$pText
```

I want to use regex to remove $ sign and one letter after that sign. How can i do this?

Comment: Just str_replace to remove $ but i have no solution for one char after.

Comment: This is very simple if you just read the documentation for regex, and knows your input well. (The harder part is the second part - we don't know what kind of input you have. Only one example will give you several different answers, each with slightly different behaviour in edge cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
echo preg_replace('/\$\w/', '', $string)
```